# Can Einstein relation be used to calculate mobility under equilibrium dynamics?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, semiconductor-physics, molecular-dynamics

In weak field non-equilibrium dynamics, mobility can be calculated by
Einstein relation $\mu=\frac{eD}{K_BT}$, where $D$ is diffusion constant.

Mobility can also be calculated by the definition $\mu=\frac{v}{F}$, where $v$ is drift velocity and $F$ is external field.

Question:

1. What if there is no drift (equilibrium dynamics), does the mobility $\mu=0$? Does this result contradict with Einstein relation?
2. what if external field $F$ becomes large enough and it's beyond linear response theory? Einstein relation collapses for far non-equilibrium area. How to calculate the diffusion constant and mobility?

Comment: Yes, indeed you can.

Comment: I edited the question, pls take a look.

Comment: In equilibrium, things still move. So, yes, there is mobility.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly the comments of @JonCuster have answered your question, but in case it helps, here are some additional thoughts.

This is the topic of *linear response theory*. A typical *static* example, which makes a good analogy, is when you imagine measuring the response of a polar molecule in a liquid to an applied electric field. At equilibrium, the average dipole moment in any direction, say $x$, is $\langle p_x\rangle_0=0$. The subscript $0$ means that we are averaging in an *unperturbed* ensemble. But if we apply a small external electric field $E_x$,
which can be thought of as introducing a perturbation term $-p_x E_x$ in the energy, the induced dipole  will be proportional to $E_x$:
$$
\langle p_x\rangle = \alpha E_x \quad\Rightarrow\quad 
\alpha = \frac{\langle p_x\rangle}{E_x} \tag{1}
$$
where now we are averaging in a perturbed ensemble. Linear response theory (I won't reproduce the whole derivation) tells us that we can also express the response coefficient $\alpha$ as an *equilibrium* ensemble average of dipole *fluctuations*
$$
\alpha = \frac{\langle p_x^2\rangle_0}{k_BT} \tag{2}
$$
where $k_B$ is Boltzmann's constant and $T$ is the temperature.
In the case of eqn (1), we can allow $E_x\rightarrow 0$ and $\langle p_x\rangle\rightarrow 0$ while their ratio $\alpha$ remains well defined. And eqn (2) makes it clear that one can still define $\alpha$ even in the absence of an external field.
(I've used a classical statistical mechanics version  of this, but very similar ideas turn up when considering the polarizability of an atom in quantum mechanics, relating it to dipolar fluctuations of the atom's electron cloud, using perturbation theory).

Turning to the mobility, dynamical linear response theory gives us an expression for the steady state drift velocity $v_x$ of a molecule in a liquid which has been subjected to a constant external force $F_x$, as
\begin{align*}
\langle v_x\rangle
&=  \frac{F_x}{k_B T}  \int_{0}^\infty \langle v_x(0) v_x(t)\rangle_0 \, d t
\\
\Rightarrow\quad \mu \equiv \frac{\langle v_x\rangle}{F_x}
&=  \frac{1}{k_B T}  \int_{0}^\infty \langle v_x(0) v_x(t)\rangle_0 \, d t  = \frac{D}{k_BT}.
\end{align*}
On the right we have the time integral of an *equilibrium* quantity, the velocity autocorrelation function. The link with the diffusion coefficient comes from noting that the displacement can be expressed as 
$$
\Delta x(t) = x(t)-x(0) = \int_0^t v_x(t') dt'
$$
and working out the mean-squared displacement at long times. Again I've omitted the details (you can easily look them up). So we get the Einstein relation (your version has an extra factor $e$ which probably means that you are thinking of the *electrical mobility*, defined in terms of the electric field, rather than the mobility, defined in terms of the applied force).
But once again, it is always possible to allow $F_x\rightarrow 0$ and $\langle v_x\rangle\rightarrow 0$ while their ratio remains well defined, and the equilibrium time correlation function formula emphasizes that the mobility itself is still defined even in the absence of an external field.

Comment: Thanks, considering both positive and negative direction the molecule or electron can move to, the ensemble average displacement $\Delta x(t)$ should be 0, correct? And then $⟨v_x⟩$=0?

Comment: In the *equilibrium* ensemble, with no field or force applied, yes, that is correct.

Comment: But by Einstein relation $\mu$ is nonzero, isn't this contradictory？

Comment: My answer addresses this point. The mobility is nonzero. As the applied force or field tends to zero, the response to it also tends to zero, and the ratio of the two quantities remains constant. There is no contradiction.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Prof. I want to numerically calculate the mobility by $\mu=v/F$ but failed, maybe that's why I thought it would be 0.

Comment: Sorry to bother you a further question, what if $F$ becomes large enough and it's beyond linear response theory? How to calculate the diffusion constant and mobility? I also re-edited my original question

Comment: The mobility (and similar linear response coefficients) are only properly defined in the regime where the response varies linearly with the applied field. In principle, this should be checked (by measuring the response as a function of the field) in any experiment. One can plot the response against the field, for instance, and measure the limiting gradient of the plot at low field.  Of course, in some areas of physics, this kind of checking has already been done, and people have gained some empirical "feel" for reasonable values of the field.